# why doesn't it execute text file?

Tags: linux, bash, visual-studio

```
#!/bin/bash
touch network_detials.txt

while true; do
ifconfig -a | cat >> network_detials.txt
done
```

Not executing properly or creating .txt file from TOUCH creation

Comment: "Not executing properly" -- so, what actually happens? An error message? What?

Answer (score 0):

1. Piping through `cat` usually doesn't change or help anything.
2. `touch`ing the file may seem nice, but it is also superfulous since `>>` will create the file if needed.
3. Nothing about your problem indicates a problem with execution.
4. Please indent within the `while` loop.